# How to Create PopUp Window in Custom adapter class?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, popupwindow

I searched so many sites for creating popUp window but i did not get proper solution for create popup Window in Custom Adapter class, i find only for creating popUp Window in Activity class.

My problem is i am using Custom Adapter class extends ArrayAdapter, in that i have a TextView in row.xml file adapted for ArrayList. when i click that textview i want to show popUp window at the cursor point location.

Here is my code :

```
Clockin_Adapter adap = new Clockin_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.group_clkin_row, result);
            clockin.setAdapter(adap);

public static class Clockin_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataItem> {

        ArrayList<DataItem> items;
        Context con;
        int[] buttonStates;
        Time t ;

        public Clockin_Adapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<DataItem> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.con = context;
            this.items = objects;

            buttonStates=new int[objects.size()];
            for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++)
            {
            buttonStates[i]=0;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {         

             if(employeeList==null){
                    return 0;
                }
                else{
                    return employeeList.length;
                }

        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {           
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View row = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
            row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.group_clkin_row, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            } else {
                //code

                }

            }

                holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.group_name);

                holder.name.setText(item.getName());
                holder.name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        //Need PopUp window Here

                    }
                });

static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView time;

        }


please give me solution.


Thanks in advanced.
```

Answer (score -1):

Custom floating window :

u can change `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);` to `dialog.setView(//your view);`

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(con);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");
```

Comment: i am not used the listView.setOnItemClickListener , i used row.xml file adapted to my listview . that is : Clockin_Adapter adap = new Clockin_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.group_clkin_row, result);  
            clockin.setAdapter(adap);   here result is ArrayList object.

Comment: you want to show dialog when u clicked one of the item of your list... is that right?

Comment: yes.. but that dialog shows at near to that item. means which item i click in the listview the  dialog show exactly near to that item .